# WCF Returns Result but Javascript gives Error

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, wcf

I'm creating a simple Javascript call to a WCF service, and after the script has called the service, it returns and error for the call. Calling the WCF service via Fiddler returned me the  proper results though. So I tried again running the script with Fiddler running to capture the packet. It seems the script is not recognizing the result to be a valid result thus prompting error, as Fiddler again captured the correct result.

Some references:

IWorkflowService:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWorkflowService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="GetWorkflowDetails?instanceId={instanceId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    WorkflowInstance GetWorkflowDetails(string instanceId);

}

[DataContract]
public class WorkflowInstance
{
    //properties
    [DataMember]
    public string Result {get; set;}
}
```

WorkflowService.cs:

```
public class WorkflowService : IWorkflowService
{
    public WorkflowInstance GetWorkflowDetails(string instanceId)
    {
        WorkflowInstance instance = new WorkflowInstance() { Result = instanceId };

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Script on aspx page:

```
var args = getQueryVariable("instanceId");
var url = "http://localhost:56091/WorkflowService.svc/GetWorkflowDetails?instanceId="+args;
//alert(url);
$("textArea").append(url);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.responseText);
    }
});
```

Raw result from Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 02:15:00 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 49
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: Close

{"Result":"9b3f4bfb-27f0-4570-82ba-3719109bab76"}
```

Comment: When I run the script, it pops up the Error:, but with no responseText.

Comment: Did you try using `console.log()` and log entire `error` object?

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks for the suggestion, doing a log gave me more info and I am seeing something in red now, as below:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56091/WorkflowService.svc/GetWorkflowDetails?instanceId=9ee2bc3b-05fd-4c3e-ad5e-4470672c0765. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Update: Chrome developer is now showing me that there is no error and the call is returning Status Code 200, BUT the script is still returning me the error call.

Answer (score 0):

try this by writing datatype as application/json and try to put json result in var res=result 
like

```
var res=result
alert(res);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand? Still not very used to javascript. Do I include this in the function of success?

Comment: yes. you have to add it in success. Add datatype also

Comment: V2, thanks, but after adding it, it does not seem to make any difference.